# What to do about a possible attack on my server with "../../[...]../../ETC/PASSWD" in PHP?

Tags: linux, security, php

I am running a web server (no `root`) hosted by `one.com` and I once coded a little “tool” that makes funny letters out of a “normal” user input though PHP `$_GET. This stuff is so 2000 but people still use this so I kept it online.

Being afraid of attacks on the server I log all the input that includes an extraordinary amount of special characters or includes names of “system folders” or other *nix commands - and now, after a couple of years I actually received a weird input:

```
../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../ETC/PASSWD
```

I wouldn’t even have noticed I guess if it didn’t download automatically (it is a `.txt` I am pushing all that input onto and usually it displayed directly in Chrome but this time it started a download for this - might have something to do with file size although I displayed `.txt`’s much larger than that in Chrome without having to download it already)

The question is: Should I be worried? Does this look like an automated attack? Have you received similar input once? I get what it’s saying but are today’s servers really vulnerable to this simple thing? Also, why should it print the content of the file then? My script processes the input as a string and therefore no system file should be read this way.

The `$_GET` URL (`DOMAIN/a.php/?get=test`) is listed at Google so if it was a bot browsing/trying all results I wouldn’t feel as concerned as I was if someone told me that I am probably being targeted by some crackers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The question is: Should I be worried? Does this look like an automated
>   attack? Have you received similar input once? I get what it’s saying
>   but are today’s servers really vulnerable to this simple thing? Also,
>   why should it print the content of the file then? My script processes
>   the input as a string and therefore no system file should be read this
>   way.

No worries. This is not an attack but a script or something probing your server. All sites/servers are being probed all the time and you can’t—for lack of a better term—take this kind of stuff personally in any way or you’d go nuts.

And in this specific case hunting for `/etc/passwd` is quite rudimentary and nonsense on any system that uses `/etc/shadow` for actual password storage. Which accounts for pretty much 99.999% of all servers out there since about 1993 I believe.

I wouldn’t be worried but that said, maybe you could ease your mind by coding your PHP script to “firewall” against the system reading arbitrary files outside of it’s running directory.

How to do that in your case? Hard to say without seeing your code, but the general philosophy is you grab whatever input is given and then clean it to suit your data input needs. Any formatting in that data that you don’t need just gets trashed.

But in general I would no lose sleep over stuff like this.